# React.js localhost refused to connect

Tags: reactjs

I have left my react project for a while which was working fine but when I came back to it and ran on chrome, it gives a localhost refused to connect page and I cannot figure out why.

I have seen a post which said to download the extension Live Server, however, it just opens a page with the code written instead of running it.

this is my launch.json which was autocreated when I ran the debugger,

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "pwa-chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any suggestions would be great, thanks

Comment: Did you create the project using Create React App or is it custom built? Have you eject from CRA or not?

Comment: try another port? 8080 most likely would be occupied

Comment: @Ajay I have created using Create React App through the terminal, and not sure what eject from CRA means ?

Comment: @ilkerkaran I have tried `"url": "http://localhost:8000"` and `3000` but still same error

Comment: Looks like you are trying to run this from VS Code, can you try to run it from terminal? Just do `yarn start` or `npm start` in the project root

Comment: Also, every web server requires an `index.html` file to be present in the root. However in your case, `webRoot` is set to `${workspaceFolder}` which doesn't have the index.html file. I think you should try doing `yarn build` or `npm run build` and set `webRoot` to `${workspaceFolder}/build`

Comment: @Ajay okay great I did `npm start` and it works now, I didnt make a `index.html` file, everything is in my js files.